# Как добавить рекламу в расширение chrome?

Tags: chrome-extension, popup, реклама

вы не подумайте, я хороший человек, и даже лучше. Я не буду встраивать рекламу на страницу, нет. Я хочу, чтобы люди, которым понравится моё расширение и которые захотят меня поблагодарить не кидали донаты, а по нажатию кнопки в popup смотрели рекламный ролик (ведь потратить чуть-чуть времени и бесплатно посмотреть ролик захотят больше людей, чем брать деньги из своего кошелька). Да, я знаю, что это будет совсем мизерно, но всё-равно мне будет приятно. Я не очень знаю html и js (я даже не знаю что такое фреймворк), и в инете ничего не нашёл, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать, или отговорите от этой идеи (лучше не надо). Спасибо.